# Gtk's XInput2 detection test doesn't work

Tags: configure, xinput

Trying to compile Gtk, configure stops with the error message:

```
configure: error: *** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details.
```

Unfortunately, config.log does not contain any extra info, all it says it is:

```
configure:23053: error: *** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details.
```

At first I had no idea to why, as I am passing libXI to configure with:

> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=....lots of stuff://media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xi-1.5.0/lib/pkgconfig/

so it should have no trouble finding it

Then I opened the file configure.ac and looked for the XInput detection test. There it is

```
if $PKG_CONFIG --exists "xi" ; then
  X_PACKAGES="$X_PACKAGES xi"
  GTK_PACKAGES_FOR_X="$GTK_PACKAGES_FOR_X xi" 
  ...
  ...
   fi
 fi  
 AS_IF([test "x$have_xinput2" != "xyes"],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details.])])
```

To try to understand whats happening, I edited the file and added:

> AC_MSG_ERROR([TRUTA])"
> right after
> if $PKG_CONFIG --exists "xi" ; then

I executed autoconf and then configure. As my error message did not show up, the first line is not working? But why? I used PKG_CONFIG_PATH to pass libXI's .pc file to it, it should work, as it worked for nearly ten other libraries

So what's wrong. It is possible that this is the wrong library? Or that it is the wrong version?

Reading the libXI detection test, it mentions the XInput2.h file, which is present in:

> include/X11/extensions/XInput2.h

of the Xi directory,

So at first sight, I would say I am using the correct library.

P.S: creating a sym link to libXI's pc file on the system dirs

> /usr/lib/pkgconfig/

and

> /usr/share/pkgconfig/

did not work
Could someone shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found

If I replace:

> if $PKG_CONFIG --exists "xi" ; then

on configure.ac, by:

```
if $PKG_CONFIG --print-errors --exists "xi" ; then
```

and then execute autoconf, it will generate a new configure based on this "new" configure.ac that will print all the required libraries that should be passed to configure.

First it was the .pc file of libXi, then the pc. file of Inputproto (that I had to download and install) an so on. I also really had to add libXi's include dir to CPPFLAGS, so it could find XInput2.h.

My final configure command was:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.41.2/lib/ CPPFLAGS="-I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/include/ -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xorgproto-2018.1/include/ -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xi-1.5.0/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/" ./configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Gtk+-3.4.0 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.41.2/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Atk-2.15.4/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Pango-1.30.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Cairo-1.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Gdk-pixbuf-2.30.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Pixman-0.18.4/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Fontconfig-2.8.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Freetype-2.2.1/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Png-1.2.14/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xi-1.5.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Inputproto-1.5.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xorgproto-2018.1/share/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xcb-1.4/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Pthread-stubs-0.1/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xau-1.0.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xext-1.1.1/lib/pkgconfig/